# Display multiple files in Linux/Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep, ls

I'm looking to display 3 different files, if they exist. I thought the following would work, but it doesn't:

```
ls -R | grep 6-atom2D.vector$ 6-atom2D.klist 6-atom2D.struct
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `ls -R | grep 6-atom2D`

Comment: There are a lot more files that start with 6-atom2D, but I just want those 3. But the command I used only displays the first one.

Comment: `ls -R | egrep  '6-atom2D\.(vector|klist|struct)'`

Comment: you want those exact file names?  or all files that begin with those 3  strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -R | egrep "6-atom2D\.vector$|6-atom2D\.klist|6-atom2D\.struct"
```

If `$` is supposed to be end of line regexp, then you might need to use `\>` instead. That works for me at least.

Edit: Backslash before `.`

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the (base) filenames, you can use `find`:

```
find . -name '6-atom2D.vector$' -o -name '6-atom2D.klist' -o -name '6-atom2D.struct'
```

It searches recursive by default.
For case-insensitive search, use `-iname` instead.